# Vim auto complete

Tags: vim, macvim

So I know you can get Vim autocompletion with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> but I'm wondering if you could rework it so it works with just pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> (more like Textmate's snippets), or even just how I could remap it to something a bit shorter (even if I can't get fancy tab completion), as I find <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> a bit awkward.

Comment: Have a look on snippets plugin, there are many. SnipMate may work for you. But the best advice I can give you is that if it doesn't work, go back to TextMate.

Comment: @sidyll I will have a look at SnipMate, thanks. I'm reluctant to go back to Textmate as I love everything about Vim apart from this small niggle!

Comment: `SnipMate` or `xptemplate` are not the same as `OmniComplete`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Map <kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>

```
:imap <tab> <c-x><c-o>
```

See [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Smart_mapping_for_tab_completion) from [vim-wiki](http://vim.wikia.com) for a smarter <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion

Comment: But now I can't use `tab` normally to tab code around as required, I'm wondering if there's a way to make tab act normally most of the time but cleverly sense when I need it to auto-complete. I understand I'm being really awkward, thanks for helping :)

Comment: See the link I added there. I think that's good for what you want.

Comment: You could also change it to something else like <c-p> if you're looking for a simple solution. It would be less awkward than <c-x><c-o> but wouldn't mess up your tab.

Comment: Thanks c00kiemon5ter, that link was exactly what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 26):

I realize this question has been already answered, but you might be interested in a plugin such as [SuperTab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643), which provides  auto-completion and uses more than one type of auto-completion depending on the context and what type of completion you have been using.

Answer (score 10):

The latest version of VIM includes auto complete
Go to insert mode at specified line <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> then
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> while in the insert mode.